# Kong configuration file not loading the new modifications

Tags: docker, kong, api-gateway

Hello I have a Kong docker image, and I modified the Kong configuration file, but when I reload my Kong container, it does not take into consideration the new modifications(adding a customized plugin and the path of it) I've saved the file but when reloading it loads with the basic default configuration, I actually don't know what's wrong and why the new kong.conf is not loading, so please if anyone has an answer or know how to modify the conf file with success let me know.

Comment: What are the steps you take to reload your kong container

Comment: I change the conf file in /etc/kong/ then I run : 
(docker exec -it kong kong reload )
I also tried running another container but with no use

Comment: Hey, did you find the solve for this issue?

Comment: Sorry @NitishJain I droped using kong, I don't remember the solution